# Unable to maintain JDBC connection using Oracle XE

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, liquibase, oracle-xe

I've set up an Oracle XE database to do some testing with an application. This application uses JDBC to work with the database. In particular, I'm using Liquibase to add/update the schema.

My JDBC connection url is: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/xe

I can confirm that it gets to the database as it manages to create two tables before it errors out:

```
liquibase.exception.LockException: liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
        at liquibase.lockservice.LockService.releaseLock(LockService.java:152)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:117)
        at com.company.liquibase.LiquibaseAdapter.update(LiquibaseAdapter.java:53)
        at com.company.startup.LiquibaseInitializingBean.afterPropertiesSet(LiquibaseInitializingBean.java:42)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFac
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactor
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.ja
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.jav
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:472)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:388)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
        at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcDatabaseSnapshotGenerator.hasTable(JdbcDatabaseSnapshotGenerator.java:63)
        at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcDatabaseSnapshotGenerator.hasDatabaseChangeLogLockTable(JdbcDatabaseSnapshotGenerator.java:49)
        at liquibase.database.AbstractDatabase.hasDatabaseChangeLogLockTable(AbstractDatabase.java:549)
        at liquibase.lockservice.LockService.releaseLock(LockService.java:135)
        ... 30 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.getMetaData(PhysicalConnection.java:5216)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.getMetaData(DelegatingConnection.java:345)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.getMetaData(PoolingDataSource.java:245)
        at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcDatabaseSnapshotGenerator.getMetaData(JdbcDatabaseSnapshotGenerator.java:258)
        at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcDatabaseSnapshotGenerator.hasTable(JdbcDatabaseSnapshotGenerator.java:54)
        ... 33 more
```

This works perfectly fine with my company Oracle database, I just can't get it to work with XE. I imagine there must be some kind of setting that I don't have configured in XE, but I'm not really sure what that would be. It seems like the connection is being closed when it shouldn't be.

I tried multiple ojdbc drivers to no avail, as well. I am able to put the connection settings in SQL Developer and easily access the database. I also use a validation query of "SELECT 1 FROM DUAL".

If there's more information that I could provide that I haven't, let me know.

Comment: Just some wild ideas: Do you open multiple connection to the same DB ? Do you use the _same_ connection from _different threads_ ?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux I believe at the point it's failing, it is only opening a single connection, but that it may be opening and closing it for each table creation. It seems like maybe the connection is being passed to the pool and being closed but not properly evicted, but the validation query should prevent that from happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was Oracle XE does not allow partitioning. Unfortunately, the errors and stack traces I was getting were not at all helpful, so that's why it wasn't obvious why it was failing.